# Basic I2C read/write failure on Beaglebone

Tags: c++, eclipse, beagleboneblack, i2c, beagleboard

I am writing a program to access WHO_AM_I registers on Accelerometer and Gyroscope via i2c on beaglebone black. Here is the basic code.`

```
int main(void)
{
char rxBuffer[40];
char txBuffer[32];
int gyroAddress = 0x20;
int acceleroAddress = 0x1e;
int tenBitAddress = 0;
int opResult = 0;


int i2cFD = open("/dev/i2c-1",O_RDWR);
opResult = ioctl(i2cFD, I2C_TENBIT, tenBitAddress);
opResult = ioctl(i2cFD,I2C_SLAVE, acceleroAddress);

memset(rxBuffer, 0, sizeof(rxBuffer));
memset(txBuffer, 0, sizeof(txBuffer));

txBuffer[0] = 0x0D;
opResult = write(i2cFD, txBuffer, 1);
if (opResult !=1) printf("No ACK bit!\n");
opResult = read(i2cFD, rxBuffer, 1);

printf("Part ID: %d\n", (int)rxBuffer[0]);


//for gyro
opResult = ioctl(i2cFD, I2C_SLAVE, gyroAddress);
txBuffer[0] = 0x0C;
opResult = write(i2cFD, txBuffer, 1);
if (opResult != 1) printf("No ACK bit!\n");
opResult = read(i2cFD, rxBuffer, 1);
printf("Part ID: %d\n", (int)rxBuffer[0]);
}
```

`
I get Part ID for both as zero but when I probe the sensor using i2cget commands it gives me the expected "0xC7" value. Any idea what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Can you try accessing the port using normal i2c tools like i2cdetect? Also, make sure i2c bus is enabled. What OS are yo,u running? (and why is eclipse specifically tagged?), take a look here: elinux.org/Interfacing_with_I2C_Devices#Beagleboard_I2C2_Enable

Comment: Yes I can access the device with i2c tools. The bus is enabled. I am running Angstrong distro on the Beaglebone, Eclipse indigo for cross compiling on Ubuntu VMware on a windows machine. The issue was in the way instructions were passed on to the sensor. It needed to be in seperate register and data format. First send the register address and then explicitly send the data to write. For the read function, I still can't point out what the fault is.

Comment: You are not checking the return values of open, ioctl and read, see the examples here: http://elinux.org/Interfacing_with_I2C_Devices , so there might be an earlier problem. and why not print the entire buffer instead of only the first byte of the array?